# Cannot link up Heroku with Git bash on windows 7(32 bit)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, git, bash, heroku

If have installed the Git Bash and Heroku CLI separately.I am using a 32-bit windows operating system.When I am typing " heroku login" command in cmd I am getting the login option but in Git Bash its showing Heroku command not found.

```
# MINGW32:/
HOME@HOME-PC MINGW32 /
$ heroku login
bash: heroku: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce this issue, but it seems pretty common and known.

According to this is [issue on Github heroku-cli project](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/84#issuecomment-170681264),

> I closed out Git Bash then opened the command prompt. From there, I
>   was able to successfully login to heroku through "heroku login". I
>   then closed the command prompt and re-launched Git Bash and everything
>   worked fine.

This workaround worked for a few people, however the issue is still open.

Comment: @shashwata any news on this question? what is helpful this answer?